# XPath : How to get concatenated text of two sibling nodes?

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I would like to know how to get concatenated text of two sibling nodes.

This is my code.

```
string html =
    "<html>" +
    "   <div class='abc'>" +
    "       <h3><a href='def'>ghi</a></h3>" +
    "       <div>text1</div>" +
    "       <div>text2</div>" +
    "   </div>" +
    "   <div class='abc'>" +
    "       <h3><a href='jkl'>mno</a></h3>" +
    "       <div>text3</div>" +
    "       <div>text4</div>" +
    "   </div>" +
    "</html>";
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='abc']");
HtmlNodeCollection nodes2, nodes3;
foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
{
    nodes2 = node.SelectNodes(".//h3/a");
    nodes3 = node.SelectNodes("?????????????");
}
```

I want to get result

```
text1text2
```

and then

```
text3text4
```

How do I write a query replace of question marks? I know I can get text with iterating through nodes using foreach. But I must do this with XPath query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mathias Müller 's comment is answer.

SelectNodes returns node list and we must navigate through collection nodes with C# programming.

The mistake is that I'm waiting text result.

Answer (score 2):

```
concat(//div[@class='abc'][1]/div[1]/text(), //div[@class='abc'][1]/div[2]/text())
```

should give: text1text2

```
concat(//div[@class='abc'][2]/div[1]/text(), //div[@class='abc'][2]/div[2]/text())
```

should give text3text4

This should work with XPATH 1.0 which is used in htmlagilitypack.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand, but given that an outer `div` element is your context, the following expression:

```
concat(div[1],div[2])
```

would return the concatenation of the string values of the first and second child `div` elements.

---

By the way, `h3` is an immediate child of `/html/div`, so there is no need to use `//` in this expression:

```
nodes2 = node.SelectNodes(".//h3/a");
```

You might want to reduce it to

```
nodes2 = node.SelectNodes("h3/a");
```

Comment: I tried `concat(div[1],div[2])` But I'm getting "Expression must evaluate to a node-set" error.

Comment: @ErcanOrak The result of this expression is a string, not a set of nodes. I'm not familiar with C# and the environment you are using, but you'd need to find a way to select values, not nodes.